# How to use integration by parts to solve an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having trouble with solving this integral by parts. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Solve the integral $\int x^3\sqrt{x^2-1}dx$ by parts, choosing u = $x^2$ and
$dv = x\sqrt{x^2-1} dx$

$du_1 = 2xdx$

$v_1$ = $\int x\sqrt{x^2-1}dx$ $ t = x^2-1$ $dt = 2x dx$

$v_1$ = $\frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{t}dt$

$v_1$ = $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{3}t^\frac{3}{2}) + c$

$v_1$ = $\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2} + c$

$uv - \int vdu$

= $\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}x^2 - \int 2x\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}dx$

$u_2 = 2x$ $dv_2 = \frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}dx$

$du_2 = 2dx$

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use integration by parts for $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}\int 2x (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}dx$.

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}\int 2x (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}dx=\frac{1}{3}\int(x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}d(x^2-1)$$

So the integral is

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{3}\int(x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}d(x^2-1)&=\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}x^2 - \frac{2}{15}(x^2-1)^\frac{5}{2}+C\\
&=\frac{1}{15}(x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}[5x^2-2(x^2-1)]+C\\
&=\frac{1}{15}(x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}(3x^2+2)+C\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Ok, but what about $\frac{1}{3}(x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2} x^2$ is the $x^2$ supposed to be there?

Comment: Your work is correct. I think you have problems in $\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}x^2 - \int 2x\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}dx$.  $ \frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}x^2$ of course is part of the answer.

Comment: So it is  $ \frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{3}\int(x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}d(x^2-1)$

Comment: I'm still not really sure where I went wrong

Comment: You haven't made mistakes. $\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}x^2 - \int 2x\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}dx$ is correct. But you don't have to use integration by parts again.

Comment: I used sub for $\int 2x \frac{1}{3}(x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}$ and I got $\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{5}(x^2-1)^\frac{5}{2})$

Comment: It's correct again.

Comment: So how come the answer is a little bit different when I use sub for the whole thing for the original question? When I use sub for the original question I get $\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{5} (x^2-1)^\frac{5}{2}$

Comment: Please read my edited answer.

Comment: I'm just wondering why the answer is kinda different when I use sub for the original integral.

Comment: You have $\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}x^2 - \int 2x\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}dx$ in your work. You also have $ \int 2x\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}dx=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{5}(x^2-1)^\frac{5}{2})$ which is also correct. So it should be $\frac{1}{3} (x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{5}(x^2-1)^\frac{5}{2})$

Comment: Alright, got it now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would make the substitution $u=x^2-1$ first.  This makes the integral

$$\frac{1}{2}\int (u-1)\sqrt{u} \; du.$$

Parts will work on this integral, but it's not the easiest way.

Comment: I know how to do it using substitution but the question asks me to do it by parts picking $u = x^2$ and $dv = x\sqrt{x^2-1} dx$

Answer (score 0):

You used integration by parts once. And you used substitution to find $v_1$. Use substitution again:
$$I=\int 2x\cdot \frac13(x^2-1)^{3/2}dx;$$
$$t=x^2-1; \ \ dt=2xdx;$$
$$I=\frac13 \int t^{3/2}dt=\frac13\cdot \frac25 \cdot t^{5/2}+C=\frac{2}{15}(x^2-1)^{5/2}+C.$$